# Is there a non-recursive way of separating each list elements into their own list?

Tags: python, list, recursion, element

I was looking at Wikipedia's pseudo-code (and other webpages like sortvis.org and sorting-algorithm.com) on merge sort and saw the preparation of a merge uses recursion.

I was curious to see if there is a non-recursive way to do it.

Perhaps something like a `for each i element in list, i=[i-th element]`.

I am under the impression that recursion is *keep-it-to-a-minimum-because-it's-undesirable*, and so therefore I thought of this question.

The following is a pseudo-code sample of the recursive part of the merge-sort from Wikipedia:

```
function merge_sort(list m)
    // if list size is 1, consider it sorted and return it
    if length(m) <= 1
        return m
    // else list size is > 1, so split the list into two sublists
    var list left, right
    var integer middle = length(m) / 2
    for each x in m up to middle
         add x to left
    for each x in m after or equal middle
         add x to right
    // recursively call merge_sort() to further split each sublist
    // until sublist size is 1
    left = merge_sort(left)
    right = merge_sort(right)
```

Comment: Thanks Reddy for the improved formatting.

Comment: This is an algorithm question rather than an implementation or language question, and ought to be identified/tagged accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bottom-up merge sort](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_merge_sort) is a non-recursive variant of merge sort.

See also this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation) for a more detailed pseudocode implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
middle = len(lst) / 2
left = lst[:middle]
right = lst[middle:]
```

List slicing works fine.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant recursion when creating the left/right splits of the list. For non-recursion of the actual sort, use the bottum-up as unutbu mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside - **recursion is not undesirable** per se.

Recursion is undesirable if you have limited stack space (are you afraid of *stackoverflow*? ;-) ), or in some cases where the time overhead of function calls is of great concern.

For much of the time these conditions do not hold; readability and maintainability of your code will be more relevant.  Algorithms like merge sort make more sense when expressed recursively in my opinion.